# Reducing Second-Order Partial Differential Equation to Canonical Form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to reduce the following equation to canonical form and to find general solution.
$$u_{xx} + 2u_{xy} +u_{yy} = 0$$

I found canonical form as $4u_{\eta\eta}+3u_{\xi\eta}=0.$ Is it right?

But I can' t find general solution from the canonical form. 
Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: A better way to do this would be to notice that $$(\partial_{xx} + 2\partial_{xy} + \partial_{yy}) u = (\partial_{x} + \partial_{y})^{2} u$$ This should help you determine if your canonical form is correct. And to solve your canonical form as it is now, integrating with respect to $\eta$ gives $$4u_{\eta} + 3u_{\xi} = f(\xi)$$ This is just an inhomogeneous advection equation.

Comment: what characteristic curves you got?

Comment: Dear Mattos, Could you explain how did you find the equation $(\partial_{xx} + 2\partial_{xy} + \partial_{yy}) u = (\partial_{x} + \partial_{y})^{2} u$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Characteristic equation $$\big(\frac{d y}{d x}\big)^2-2\frac{d y}{d x}+1=0$$ gives only one characteristic curve, $$y-x=constant.$$ So, taking $\xi=y-x$ and $\eta=y$, the given equation reduces to $$u_{\eta \eta}=0.$$

Comment: Thanks. I guess I made the mistake operation while finding canonical form. It is quitely complicate. Is there any shortcuts to find canonical form or to check that it is right?

Comment: You can check the sign of discriminant($B^2-4AC$), which does not changes under a canonical transformation.

Comment: @ak. Sorry if I enter in the question. I read it and I wanted a confirm.
If I'm understanding correctly, the equation
$$ u_{xx} -6u_{xt} + 9u_{tt}=0$$
produces just one arbitrary function?
So, is the general solution $ u(x,t)=\Phi(t+3x)$ right and correct, without any other sum?  Thanks